# как сделать регулярное выражение javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angularjs

нужно чтобы регулярное выражение запрещало писать пробелы и все символы кроме нижнего подчеркивания и дефиса , запрет пробелы и все остальные символы. Так же разрешить писать буквы английские в любом регистре. Цифры тоже разрешить. 
Я смог додуматься до этого но оно не работает

```
$scope.matchPatternPassword = new RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_]");
```

Comment: _оно не работает_ потому что ты сам разрешаешь пробел и остальные символы в части `! @#$%^&*()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно запретить ввод пробелов, зачем добавлять его в символьный класс? То же касается символов `!@#$%^&*()` - если они "под запретом", их тоже необходимо удалить из символьного класса.

Так как вам необходимо проверить целую строку на наличие букв и цифр ASCII + `-` и `_`, символьный класс нужно квантифицировать и заключить в метасимволы `^` (начало строки) и `$` (конец строки).

В общем, используйте

```
$scope.matchPatternPassword = /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/;
```

Что равносильно написанию

```
$scope.matchPatternPassword = /^[\w-]*$/;
```

где

- `^` - начало строки
- `[\\w-]*` - 0 и более (`*`, для 1 и более повторений используйте `+`) букв и цифр ASCII, а также знаков `_` и `-`
- `$` - конец строки

Не забудьте добавить

```
ng-trim="false"
```

иначе можно вводить сколько угодно пробелов в начале и конце строки.

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.matchPatternPassword = /^[\w-]*$/;
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        console.log("form submitted");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="myfield" ng-pattern="matchPatternPassword" required ng-trim="false"> 
    <span ng-show="myForm.myfield.$error.pattern">Неправильный формат!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
new RegExp("[-_a-zA-Z0-9]")
```