# Функция .test показывает неверный результат регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Друзья, помогите понять в чем подвох.

У меня есть выражение:

```js
var searchText = "sdf@3";
if (!/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇъЪёЁґҐ\-\s]+/gi.test(searchText))
  console.log(searchText + ' is valid');
else
  console.log(searchText + ' is not valid');
```

в переменной searchText у меня должны быть слова на латинице или кирилице, допускаются пробелы и дефисы и все.

При тестировании моего шаблона [на этом сайте](https://regexr.com) валидация работает как надо, но в реальной среде в js у меня совсем другие результаты. Пропускаются и цифры, и символы. К примеру **sdf@3** валидно. В чем подвох?

Вот что у меня:

[image: Код]
[image: Результат]

Comment: А сниипет Ваш говорит, что не валидно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Снипет добавил я для лучшей демонстрации кода, и да, он действительно невалидный.

Comment: Удалите модификатор `g` (и тоже `i` можно) и добавьте `$` в конце выражения. `/^[a-zA-Zа-яёЁА-ЯіІїЇъЪёЁґҐ\s-]+$/`.

Comment: Действительно на представленном сниппете все ок, но у меня конкретно почему то результаты наоборот.  Пример того что у меня я изобразил в вопросе (обновил текст)

Comment: Чтобы помочь вам, лучше опубликуйте ссылку на Codepen/JFiddle с неработающим примером.

Comment: А если добавить `$` в конец выражения, и в условии убрать `!`..?

Comment: В сниппете по сравнению с кодом на скрине перепутаны сообщения об ошибках

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а зачем `g` удалять?

Comment: @Grundy Если нужно узнать, есть совпадение или нет, зачем пытаться искать один и тот же шаблон несколько раз? [Чрезмерное использование `g` сами знаете, до чего доводит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752712/182013). Да, тут другой случай, но есть best practices.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, может лучше какой-то еще вопрос похожий поискать или эталонный вопрос-ответ сделать? Может лучше [этот вопрос как дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/811044/186999) указать?

Comment: @Grundy Нет, тот вопрос специфичен, связан с AngularJS, там свои подвохи. То, что я нашёл, вполне подходит в качестве минималистичного эталонного.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ок, бахнул.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в то регулярном выражении: сейчас оно проверяет что *строка **начинается с** кириллицы, латиницы или пробелов и `-`*.

И если проверяемую строку заменить на `@3sdf`, то условие отработает верно:

```js
var searchText = "@3sdf";
if (!/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇъЪёЁґҐ\-\s]+/gi.test(searchText))
  console.log(searchText + ' is not valid');
else
  console.log(searchText + ' is valid');
```

Чтобы вся строка соответствовала регулярному выражению нужно добавить символ конца строки: `$`

```js
var searchText = "sdf@3";
if (!/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇъЪёЁґҐ\-\s]+$/gi.test(searchText))
  console.log(searchText + ' is not valid');
else
  console.log(searchText + ' is valid');
```

---

Как подсказывает [@WiktorStribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872348/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-test-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment1414371_872348) - из полученной регулярки можно убрать флаги `g` и `i`.

```js
var searchText = "sdf@3";
if (!/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯіІїЇъЪёЁґҐ\-\s]+$/.test(searchText))
  console.log(searchText + ' is not valid');
else
  console.log(searchText + ' is valid');
```

Comment: Я действительно перепутал условия. Спасибо!